# Detect that an item has changed after it is tagged

Tags: client-object-model, tagging, tags

I am using the Client Object Model to work with SharePoint items and also the 'SocialDataService.asmx' web service to work with tags.

I use the 'Modified' field of a SharePoint item to detect whether it has changed (some field value has changed) but it seems that adding/deleting of tags on an item does not affect the value of the 'Modified' field.

How do I detect a change in an item if all that has changed is it's tag(s)?

Comment: what vesion of SP are you using? 2010/3 Found/Std/Ent ? And how are you 'tagging' the list item?

Comment: SP 2010. I tag the item via the UI and also via calling the SocialDataWebService.AddTag method